# Nginx reverse proxy for websocket and normal HTTP traffic with ssl

Tags: https, nginx, websocket, mojolicious

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can nginx be used as a reverse proxy for a backend websocket server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419346/can-nginx-be-used-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-a-backend-websocket-server)

I'm writing a webapp using mojolicous for my backend. Using nginx as reverse proxy in front of my hypnotoad webserver made my site accessible via ssl but not the websocket. Is there a way to proxy websocket and non-websocket traffic to the same port with nginx?

I would really appreciate every hint/link/help to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2419346/289985

Comment: Well, this was posted in 2010. There is a possible solution using Stunnel+HAProxy+Webserver I guess - I have not tried it yet - but maybe also a cleaner approach?